# How to push a local repository to remote use "SourceTree"

Tags: git, repository, atlassian-sourcetree

As the title says, I use GIT by SourceTree.

My question is **how can I create a remote repository by SourceTree directly ?**

For example, I have a directory named "Test" at local. 
There is some text file in "Test" and the remote server doesn't have any repository.

Now, I need push "Test" to server. 
Is there any way to create a remote repository **by SourceTree**?

Not using command line or other way, Just use SourceTree(Which button or how setting... etc. ?)
(I found a command line is "scp -r LocalFileName RemoteFilePath".)
Hope them has same effect.

p.s. I'm using SSH

Comment: After 6 years the situation remains same. Github desktop provides the option with gh command, but I don't like the Github desktop GUI

Answer (score 10):

I tried this on SourceTree 1.6+

Click `View -> Hosted Repositories`
Here you will see all your remote repositories.

Click the buttom at the bottom `Create New Repository...`
This will allow you to create a new repo on Bitbucket. Enter name and create your repo.

Once you see your new repository in the list, right click on it and click `Copy Project URL to Clipboard`

Now use this URL in the `URL/Path` field for the Remote details when you add a remote to your local repository.

[image]

Comment: I get the error: Permission denied (publickey). fatal: Could not read from remote repository. Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists. -- -- So how do I add my own access rights for the remote repo I just created into my local repo?

Answer (score 1):

#### Worked With

macOS Catalina 10.15.7
Sourcetree Version 4.1.2(238)

This is a very old question but the question remains relevant as the interface for this is still unintuitive in 2021.

**Scenario**: You started a repository on your local machine and want to create a remote link after the fact.

⚠️ Do NOT create the remote manually on the browser and then try to link. Big headache.

---

#### Instructions

1. Open Sourcetree
2. Go to `Window > Show Remote Hosted Repositories`
3. [image]
4. Right-click on the name of your local repo
5. [image]
6. Follow the rest of the prompts to completion